# Why is $2$-adic roots of unity $\{1,-1\}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

I am reading a proof of the fact that the only root of unity in $\mathbb Q_2$ is $\pm1$. But I am stuck at one point: The proof says that all of the root of unity in  $\mathbb Q_2$ has an order of a power of $2$. And since $-1$ is not a square in $\mathbb Q_2$, the root of unity in $\mathbb Q_2$ has to have order $2$ and thus they are just $\pm1$.

I understand the second sentence here but have no idea whether root of unity in  $\mathbb Q_2$ has order of a power of $2$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Well, the order of $-1$ is two, because the first power of it that’s equal to $1$ is the second: $(-1)^2=1$. Since the only roots of unity are $1$ and $-1$, of order one ($=2^0$) and two ($=2^1$) respectively, I think that that’s all that there is to say.

Comment: @Lubin there is more to say: the OP wants to know why the only roots of unity in $\mathbf Q_2$ are $\pm 1$. To the OP: if $n$ is odd then use Hensel's lemma on $f(x) = x^n - 1$ with $a_0 = 1$: $|f(1)|_2 = |0|_2 < 1$ and $|f'(1)|_2 = |n|_2 = 1$, so by  Hensel's lemma there is a *unique* root $\alpha$ of $f(x)$ in $\mathbf Z_2$ such that $\alpha \equiv 1 \bmod 2\mathbf Z_2$, so $x^n - 1$ has just one root in $1 + 2\mathbf Z_2$. Since $1$ is such a root, it's the only one: no root of unity has odd order in $\mathbf Z_2$ except $1$. So roots of unity in $\mathbf Z_2$ have $2$-power order.

Comment: @KCd Thank you for you answer! I actually have thought of your argument. But then I thought there were still numbers between odd numbers and a power of two, say $2\cdot$odd, e.g. 6. Why are those not possible order of root of unity?

Comment: If $z$ is a root of unity of order dividing $6$ then $z^2$ has order dividing $3$, so $z^2 = 1$. Thus $z$ has order dividing $2$.

Comment: @JKDASF: If $a$ is a root of unity of order $6$ then $a^2$ is a root of unity of order $3$.

Comment: OH YES. I should've thought of that. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly any root of unity in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ is actually in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But now note that the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/(2^n)$ has order $2^{n-1}$, so its only element of odd order is $1$.  This means that any root of unity in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ of odd order must be $1$ mod $2^n$ for all $n$, and thus must be equal to $1$.